# Java reading a file and sending it via DatagramSocket

Tags: java

Using Java, I am trying to send some file data over a DatagramSocket. I need to read a file in 1000-byte chunks and send them over as packets. My code:

1. reads a file into a byte array wrapped in a byte buffer
2. places the data in a packet and sends it
3. has the receiver open the packet and re-write the contents to a new file.

I am having a problem with writing the byte array back to a file. Please see my code below.

**Client/Sender:**

```
byte[] data = new byte[1000];
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
DatagramPacket pkt;
File file = new File(sourceFile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
CRC32 crc = new CRC32();

while(true){
    b.clear();
    b.putLong(0); // I need to put the checksum at the beginning for easy retrieval
    bytesRead = bis.read(data);
    if(bytesRead==-1) { break; }
    crc.reset();
    crc.update(data, 8, data.length-8);
    long chksum = crc.getValue();
    b.rewind();
    b.putLong(chksum);
    pkt = new DatagramPacket(data, 1000, addr); // addr is valid, works fine
    sk.send(pkt);
}

bis.close();
fis.close();
```

**Server/Receiver:**

```
DatagramSocket sk = new DatagramSocket(port);

File destfile = new File("hello.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destfile);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);

byte[] data = new byte[1000];
DatagramPacket pkt = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
CRC32 crc = new CRC32();

while(true) {
    pkt.setLength(data.length);
    sk.receive(pkt);
    b.rewind();

    // compare checksum, print error if checksum is different
    // if checksum is the same:
    bos.write(data);  // Where the problem seems to be occurring.

    // send acknowledgement packet. 
}
bos.close();
fos.close();
```

Here, I am mainly having issues with writing the file back. With a small text file that says `Hello World!`, I get a strange output that says `vˇ]rld!`. Also, the input file is only 12 bytes but the file that the receiver creates is 1KB.

I think my issue is dealing with a byte buffer - I've written a program that copies files using file streams and buffered streams, which worked well. But I'm confused with how streams work in this sort of situation, and I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Question: Why are you choosing UDP over TCP? And given that you are, are you sure that the 1,000 byte chucks make sense and can be processed independently?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Regarding the choice of protocol and chunk size, unfortunately, it's a given constraint. I have to use UDP and create packets that are 1000 bytes max.

Comment: It makes sense that your file is 1KB since you sent a 1000 byte packet.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but you should probably set the packet length based on the position of the ByteBuffer.

Comment: @aglassman Yes, you are right on both pointers - thank you! I've edited my code accordingly and it works great now. :D

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sender's data[] you overwrite the text, which was read from the file by the crc! You have to read the text in a position after the long. When correcting this in the Sender, it works:

```
//int bytesRead = bis.read(data); --old code
int bytesRead=bis.read(data,8,data.length-8);
```

Furthermore you send 1000 bytes, so will receive 1000 bytes, which will go into the destfile.

BTW: you do not check the crc in the server.... so why send it ?

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't have a good understanding of how the byte array is saving my inputs. I do check the CRC, I didn't include it in the snippet because it works fine :) 

If I may ask another question, my program is transferring (or 'copying') small files (~ few KBs) well, but it's breaking down in the middle of copying slightly larger files (~MB and most likely GB). Do I have to use a different stream when copying bigger files?

Comment: Please, could you be more specific on the breakdown? On the server or client side ? Does an exception occur?
In your application protocol there doesn't seem to be a signal when the file transfer is finished, so maybe this might be something to look at.